# Solving for $x$ when $x$ is on both sides including surds.

Tags: linear-algebra

In a text book I'm using there is the following question:

$$x\sqrt3 = x + \sqrt3.$$ Solve, giving $x$ in the form $A\sqrt B+C$.

I've checked the answer in the back of the text book but I really can't see how I can get there.

I must have attempted to rearrange the equation a dozen times and I can't get it.

Any help?

Comment: $(\sqrt{3}-1)x=\sqrt{3}$. And use it: $(\sqrt{3}-1)(\sqrt{3}+1)=2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
  x\sqrt{3}  &=& x + \sqrt{3}\\
  x\sqrt{3} - x &=& \sqrt{3}\\
  x(\sqrt{3} - 1) &=& \sqrt{3} \\
  x &=& \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3} - 1}\\
  \textrm{Now rationalize the denominator:}&&\\
  x &=& \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3} - 1}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{3} + 1}{\sqrt{3} + 1}\\
  x &=& \frac{3+\sqrt{3}}{3 - 1}\\
  x &=& \frac{3+\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
  \textrm{Finally, write in the required form:}&&\\
  x &=& \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3} + \frac{3}{2}.  
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\sqrt 3x=x+\sqrt 3\implies (\sqrt 3-1)x=\sqrt 3\implies x=\frac{\sqrt 3}{\sqrt 3-1}=\frac{\sqrt 3(\sqrt 3+1)}{(\sqrt 3-1)(\sqrt 3+1)}=\frac{3+\sqrt3}2$$

More generally,

$$\sqrt ax=bx+\sqrt c\implies x=\frac{\sqrt c}{\sqrt a-b}=\frac{\sqrt c(\sqrt a+b)}{(\sqrt a-b)(\sqrt a+b)}=\frac{\sqrt{ac}+\sqrt cb}{a-b^2}$$

If $a=c,$  $$\sqrt ax=bx+\sqrt a\implies x=\frac{a+\sqrt ab}{a-b^2}$$

Here $a=3,b=1$

Comment: Thanks, great help. I've been away from maths for a while so I forgot about this part: x(√3 - 1) Does doing that have a name, I can't remember.

Comment: @user57125, could I make the idea clear?

Comment: No, I understand it perfectly. As soon as I saw it everything came back to me. I was just wondering if the process had a specific name attached to it.

Comment: Would it by any chance be "Factorising"?

Comment: @user57125, it's http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationalisation_(mathematics)